# How can improve the performance in VS11 Metro application?

Tags: performance, windows-8

I am implementing a Windows 8 Metro application in C#, using Visual Studio 11.  I am noticing performance issues during orientation changes, and also periodically notice hangs when running the application in the simulator.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the performance of my application, perhaps including general patterns or best practices?

Comment: Are you experiencing specific performance issues?  Are you looking for general best practices?

Comment: In orientation changing some images are loading in more time and simulator some times hanging tell me general performance patterns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the images coming from the server or from local?

If from server, then you need to set Content Expiration on IIS for static files. This way the files will be cached locally.

Also try to optimize the images. You can use PngCrush to compress PNG. JPG has similar tools. You should also reduce the resolution of the images. If they are photos taken from camera, they have very high resolution like 300, 600, 1200... You should get the resolution down to 72 for screen view.

May be you can show me a screenshot?